# Spring data mongodb and scala lazy val: do not serialise bitmap$0 field

Tags: spring, scala, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use spring boot data mongodb in my scala project. When saving a case class that contains a lazy val, an additional `bitmap$0` field appears in the mongo document (even if `lazy val` field is annotated with `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`). For example:

```
case class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
  @Transient lazy val fullName: String = firstName +' ' + lastName
}

trait UserMongoRepository extends MongoRepository[User, String] 

@Service
class userService(userMongoRepository: UserMongoRepository){
  def saveUser = {
    val u = User("Bob", "Marley")
    userMongoRepository.save(u)
  }
}
```

This results in a document:

```
{"firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Marley", "bitmap$0": false}
```

How do I save a class with `lazy val` without the `bitmap$0` field?

Comment: Try annotating your lazy val with `scala.annotation.transient`

Comment: @ghik annotating lazy val with scala's `@transient` resulted in a field `"bitmap$trans$0"`.